# I need a REST API Camunda ID user?

Tags: camunda

[image]

I can't find Platform REST API, please guide me.

Answer (score 1):

Please see: https://docs.camunda.org/manual/7.18/user-guide/spring-boot-integration/rest-api/

> By default the application path is engine-rest, so without any further
> configuration you can access the api at
> http://localhost:8080/engine-rest.